# AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'isna'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

After applying `isna` to my original dataset, and saving it to a new variable.

That new variable is not acting like a dataframe and the output shows this error (AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'isna') when I look for its shape.

When I read the new dataframe, it gives the description of the new dataframe in the output.

```
df1Books = df1.dropna
print(df1Books)
```

It is giving description of the new variable df1Books

And

```
df1Books.head()


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-20-8f073fd0d9cc> in <module>
----> 1 df1Books.head()-tt

AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'head'
```

Comment: hi, better show the code and show as text; but you seem to have not called a function (with parantheses).

Comment: Thank you. putting parentheses worked